# Moved RecyclerView code directly from activity to fragment, what do these errors mean?

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I did have the following code running in `MainActivity`; but decided to move it into the `Fragment` shown below. I have solved all errors shown in the IDE, but am still struggling to debug the attached logcat on start up.

**Fragment:**

```
package mackinnoninc.packmule;


import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


//Created on 09/03/2017.
public class FragmentInventory extends Fragment implements ListAdapter.Listener {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DbHelper dbHelper;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inventory, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_contactlist);
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);

        dbHelper = DbHelper.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());


        adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), dbHelper.getAllUser());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));

        ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback =
                new SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(adapter);
        ItemTouchHelper touchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
        touchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

        totalQuantity();


        fabHideShow();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void nameToChnge(String name) {
        dbHelper.deleteRow(name);

        adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), dbHelper.getAllUser());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
    }


    public void totalQuantity() {
        /** Sums the Quantities, not currently doing anything else, but I will need it in the future
         * */
        Integer totalSum = dbHelper.getTotal();
    }

    public void introItem() {
        dbHelper = DbHelper.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        UserData userData = new UserData();
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("introItem", getActivity().getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
        Integer restoredText = prefs.getInt("introItemCheck", 0);

        if (restoredText == 0){
            userData.sort_id = 1;
            userData.name = "Adding Items";
            userData.quantity = "1";
            userData.description = "To add an item, click the add button below. To edit an item, click it." ;
            dbHelper.insertUserDetail(userData);

            userData.sort_id = 2;
            userData.name = "Absorbing Shield";
            userData.quantity = "1";
            userData.description = "+1 heavy steel shield; appears to absorb light; can disintegrate an object on touch; " +
                    "2 day cool down. Worth 25,000gp. This is an example.";
            dbHelper.insertUserDetail(userData);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("introItem", getActivity().getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putInt("introItemCheck", 1);
            editor.apply();
        }
    }


    public void fabHideShow () {
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy){
                if (dy > 0)
                    fab.hide();
                else if (dy < 0)
                    fab.show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**fragment_inventory.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"fra
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/deepBlue">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rv_contactlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:onClick="addItem"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_black_24dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/rv_contactlist"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Logcat:**

```
03-09 17:59:40.071 17173-17173/company.appname E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: company.appname, PID: 17173
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{company.appname/company.appname.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                           at company.appname.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                           at company.appname.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to company.appname.ListAdapter$Listener
                                                                           at company.appname.ListAdapter.<init>(ListAdapter.java:36)
                                                                           at company.appname.FragmentInventory.onCreateView(FragmentInventory.java:35)
                                                                           at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
                                                                           at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:949)
                                                                           at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
                                                                           at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1228)
                                                                           at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2203)
                                                                           at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5567)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:36)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                           at company.appname.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

**List Adapter:**

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ItemViewHolder>
        implements ItemTouchHelperAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = "ListAdapter";
    Context context;
    private List<UserData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Listener listener;
    DbHelper dbHelper;



    public interface Listener {
        void nameToChnge(String name);
    }

    public ListAdapter(Context context, List<UserData> dataList1) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataList = dataList1;
        this.listener= (Listener) context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recylerview_one, parent, false);
        ItemViewHolder viewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(convertView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.tv_name.setText(dataList.get(position).name);
        holder.tv_quantity.setText(dataList.get(position).quantity);
        holder.tv_description.setText(dataList.get(position).description + " ");

        holder.relLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String s = dataList.get(position).id;
                Integer stringo = Integer.parseInt(s);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemEditActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("ItemNumber", stringo);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_name, tv_quantity, tv_description;
        RelativeLayout relLayout;


        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameDisplay);
            tv_quantity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantityDisplay);
            tv_description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionDisplay);
            relLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relLayout);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemDismiss(final int position) {
        dataList.remove(position);
        dbHelper = DbHelper.getInstance(context);
        dbHelper.deleteRowItem(position + 1);
        this.notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    //Collections.swap(dataList, fromPosition, toPosition);
    //notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);


    @Override
    public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
            for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) {
                Collections.swap(dataList, i, i + 1);

            }
        } else {
            for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) {
                Collections.swap(dataList, i, i - 1);
            }
        }
        this.notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
        Log.d("fg", fromPosition + " - " + toPosition);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the fragment_inventory.xml

Comment: it says error in  fragment_inventory.xml @ line #10

Comment: I've attached the xml, and okay, however I still can't spot my error

Comment: the problem is because of using bad context. see my answer @TomJames

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
>   cannot be cast to company.appname.ListAdapter$Listener    at
>   company.appname.ListAdapter.(ListAdapter.java:36)

Seems you are casting first parameter of the `ListAdapter`'s constructor to the `company.appname.ListAdapter$Listener` somewhere in the `ListAdapter` class.

While you were using Activity implementing that interface all worked fine, but after migration to the `Fragment` you should pass `Context` and `Listener` separately.

**EDIT**

Just add 3-parameter constructor to your `ListAdapter`:

```
public ListAdapter(Context context, Listener listener, List<UserData> dataList1) {
     this.context = context;
     this.dataList = dataList1;
     this.listener = listener;
     inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
 }
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense; I don't really know how to pass `Context` and `Listener` separately, I've attached my `ListAdapter` class in my question. Can you elaborate on how I should implement your answer?

Comment: I'm sincerely sorry, but now I don't know what to put in `adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), dbHelper.getAllUser());` in my `Fragement`. Could you offer more guidance?

Comment: easily) Taking into accout that your fragment already implements `Listener` you can do it like `adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), this, dbHelper.getAllUser());`

Comment: No more errors on the IDE, but contains to prompt the exact same errors in Logcat.

Comment: Cancel that, I didn't change the `this.listener = listener` line. Everything works, thank you. I just set a bounty thinking I still hadn't received an answer, so I'll award you it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using interface in activity and implement the interface in your Adapter.

and Try changing
import android.app.Fragment;

to
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Answer (score 0):

The error is here :

```
 @Override
public void nameToChnge(String name) {
    dbHelper.deleteRow(name);
    // HERE IS THE LINE WHICH MAKE PROBLEM
    adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), dbHelper.getAllUser());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
}
```

You are passing the context of application. the context of activities and application are different. If you want to do something related to views, you should use Activity Context.

just change that line to this:

```
adapter = new ListAdapter(getContext(), dbHelper.getAllUser());
```

Answer (score 0):

add new constructor to ListAdapter

```
public ListAdapter(Context context, List<UserData> dataList1,Listener listener) {
 this.context = context;
 this.dataList = dataList1;
 this.listener = listener;
 inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
```

and change this line in your fragment

```
adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), dbHelper.getAllUser(),this);
```